# Java - Superclass (Inheritance) vs Parent class (no Inheritance)

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, nested-class

newbie here, preparing for job interviews.

I'm reading and practicing object-oriented programming concepts, however I'm stuck on why inheritance is important at all when (in Java) we can create member classes...

For example, [Oracle's official Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html), gives examples of bikes, that although there are many characteristics that are common with different types of bikes (Mountain, road or tandem bikes) but they all have their own unique different characteristics too. So to implement this, we create a class Bikes, which has all the common characteristics, and then separate classes for Mountain, road and tandem bikes, all of which inherit the bike class. Something like this....

```
class Bike {
     int speed;
     int gear;
}

class MountainBike extends Bike {
     int chain rings;
}

//classes for road bike and tandem bike etc...
```

Isn't it the same thing as following?

```
class Bike {
     int speed;
     int gear;

     class MountainBike {
         int chain rings;
     }

     //classes for Road bike or tandem bike etc...
}
```

I mean an instance created of the class MountainBike will have characteristics speed and gear too, right? And that was the whole point of inheritance, i.e. to reduce redundant data by eliminating the need to create separate data members which are common to many objects. So why do we need inheritance at all?

Thanks for your patience...

Comment: In your example `MountainBike` is an inner class of `Bike` and it is not `static`, so you could only have an instance of it when you have an enclosing instance of `Bike`. Anyways, what would you do if you wanted both `Bike` and `MountainBike` to have a `ride` method?  How would you change your design if you wanted to also have `RoadBike`, `DirtBike`, or `Tricycle`?

Comment: @MikeKobit small terminology issue - _inner_ classes cannot be static. By definition a static nested class is not an inner class because it doesn't have a containing instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example says that every `MountainBike` **is** a `Bike`. This is how it should be.

The second example says that every `MountainBike` **belongs to** a `Bike`. This makes no sense at all. For example, with your second example you could write

```
Bike bike = new Bike();
Bike.MountainBike mountainBike1 = bike.new MountainBike();
Bike.MountainBike mountainBike2 = bike.new MountainBike();
```

This would create a new `Bike` called `bike` and two `MountainBike`s that belong to `bike`.

Something that would make sense as an inner class of `Bike` would be `Wheel`. Then you could write

```
Bike bike = new Bike();
Bike.Wheel frontWheel = bike.new Wheel();
Bike.Wheel backWheel = bike.new Wheel();
```

Then you would have a `Bike` with two `Wheels` that belong to the `Bike`.

Comment: Nicely explained! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, MountainBike is *not* an extension of Bike, but instead an inner class (or nested class) of Bike. Inner classes have very specific uses, but one benefit you do not get is inheritance. Instead, inner classes are usually used as a helper class that only the parent class would need. Personally, I find that I use them rarely, because my answer is usually no, to this question: "Is the parent class the only class that would need to use this class?" So, I usually end up making a separate class instead.

Here is a reference page, from the current Java company: [Nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

**Edit**

According to that reference, there are 3 'compelling' reasons to use inner classes. Personally, I can't think of any reasons to add to the list, but I don't agree that it makes code easier to read--that is very subjective, and depends on what a developer is used to:

1. It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place
2. It increases encapsulation
3. It can lead to more readable and maintainable code

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that class `MountainBike` in your second example will only be accessible inside class `Bike`.  You need to extend `Bike` when creating `MountainBike` as it's own class, in-order for `MountainBike` to be accessible by other classes, and so that it inherits fields and methods from it's parent class `Bike`.

Answer (score 0):

why do we need inheritance ? to manage something global, like a directory.
May be i'm the manager of a bike shop, i just need to know how many bikes i have, and their prices. But as a seller i need to know if it's moutain bike, city bike, what's the difference between them